# How to send sales rep info via xero sales invoices api

Tags: xero-api

I am trying to send the sales rep info via the xero api but I dont see how to do this.

This is the api I am using

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/invoices

Comment: Add some part of your current code, please.

Comment: I am looking for where to add this data... where in the api can I put the sales rep info on an invoice?

Comment: No one knows this stuff????
Does Xero check this thread or no???